# How to combine duplicate rows in Excel where 1 column of info is different

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been trying to combine 2 or more rows of information on a spreadsheet (letters and numbers) with multiple columns BUT one column will have different words (not numbers).

I have tried to use consolidate but since it is always looking for a value/number and NOT characters I cannot figure this out.

Note that I cannot use add-ins (work computer is locked down).

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and include an image of your hoped-for result.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share the expected output since what you are trying is not clear to us !!

Comment: What's the result you want?

Comment: If you have a relatively recent version of windows Excel or Office 365, this task can usually be done easily using Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

In control failure_new column, put in **row 3** (row1 = headers, row2 = 1st data is unique so skip)

```
=if(and(b2=b3,c2=c3), D2 &  "; " & D3, D3)
```

This will also work for mutliple duplicates as the text will grow and grow. To delete or filter the duplicates, make another helper column with the following formula, starting in **row 2**

```
=if(and(b2=b3,c2=c3), "Duplicate", "Unique")
```

Now filter for "Unique" values, or filter for "Duplicate" and delete and clear filter.